# CRUD Operations with .Net core and Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on C# and sql server 2012. I am new in .Net Core. I want to cover web api 2 with .net core for my work, So i want basic idea that how CRUD operations done in web api 2 and .net core. Thank You.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer your question let me tell you something that might change the way you look at .net core.
At normal MVC .NET Framework 4.x you can either choose WebAPI2 or normal MVC.
In .net core the two are merged meaning that it doesn't really matter which one you choose. They point at the same libraries.

In terms of CRUD you can use the [HttpGet], [HttpPost], [HttpPut] and [HttpDelete] attributes to give the specific functionality to the endpoint.
If you want to get a parameter from the body of the request you can use HttpContext.Request.Form["parameter name"].

You can also use the [FromBody] attribute in the endpoint constructor to map an object to a model.

In terms of database you can use Entity Framework's code first approach to generate the database based on your models.

For in depth EF stuff you can go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you first check the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

For how to use LINQ to understand the ORM based queries that are executed here, check this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367(v=vs.110).aspx

You have examples for both query & method syntax. I prefer method, but both are ok, as long as you are consistent in your application.

**If you are going to use this Entity Framework approach, here is a short example:**

1. Define an architecture that you will use in your project such as:

   - API controller (same as normal controller in .Net Core)
   - Service Layer
   - Repo layer
2. Inside the repo layer inject the AppplicationDbContext and write methods such as:

`GetAllAsync(), GetByIdAsync, UpdateAsync(), DeleteAsync(), CreateAsync()` ...

3. Expose this through the interface to the service layer. Add any business logic in the service layer that you need.
4. Then inside your api controller you can use for example something like this:

   await _serviceName.GetAllAsync()..
5. Return the result as JSON or any other format that you need.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api